# Importing Bootstrap Theme damage CSS and JS of Odoo 9. How should I fix it?

Tags: javascript, css, themes, odoo, odoo-9

I have been working for days importing a Bootstrap theme to Odoo 9. I have done it successfully, but some how my theme's JS and CSS files conflict with Odoo administrator theme layout --messing everything up. What do you recommend me to do?

Example: [Here is, how it shows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuRAe.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my problem!!! If you experience conflict with CSS classes and JS functions in Odoo or any other platform after you import your own Bootstrap theme do as follow:

1. Identify those classes and functions that are in conflict in the platform.
2. Open your CSS and JS Bootstrap files. (I recommend programs like Sublime Text and Brackets)
3. Find and replace for a similar name in the entire document --for example **dropdown** to **Qdropdown** to CSS classes and JS functions.

Be careful with the Community version of Odoo. That platform is strategically designed so we fall in they hands for support, bugs, and many other things. They on purpose limited the platform to cash out from it --forcing us for the pay version. Be smart and figure out things by yourself.

All HTML website could be import in to Odoo 9. If you buy a theme from Odoo.S.A, those Odoo theme are not able to work on mobile devices.

Good luck!